# How to fadeIn the first background image?

Tags: css, css-animations

I have a header with the background being animated between two images.

```
header {
    margin-top: 80px; /* navbar height */
    padding-top: 60px !important;
    padding-bottom: 50px !important;
    background: rgba(255,215,0,1) !important;
    background-size: cover;
    /*
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center top;*/
    -webkit-animation: animation-home-background 15000ms infinite;
    -moz-animation: animation-home-background 15000ms infinite;
    -o-animation: animation-home-background 15000ms infinite;
    animation: animation-home-background 15000ms infinite;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-delay: 1s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animation-home-background {
    25%    {background-image: url("../img/header/h2.jpg"); }
    50%   {background-image: url("../img/header/h1.jpg"); }
    100%  {background-image: url("../img/header/h2.jpg"); }
}
@keyframes animation-home-background {
    25%    {background-image: url("../img/header/h2.jpg"); }
    50%   {background-image: url("../img/header/h1.jpg"); }
    100%  {background-image: url("../img/header/h2.jpg"); }
}
```

Now the first image just appears out of the blue. How can I make sure that the first image fades in smoothly from the yellow background color?

Comment: Provide a working example. We can't know how background is blue or how is yellow. We can't see what's the problem. Read that: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve IMPORTANT

Comment: And I think your problem is the `!important` in the `background` property outside the animation (`background: rgba(255,215,0,1) !important;`)

Comment: I think you may also want to pre-load your first image.

Comment: How do you pre-load the first image?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't understand exactly what you want because you have used code paths for images related to your project.

Even so, I developed a prototype in JSFiddle which replaces your images by colors and cut off all "!important".

```
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
    -webkit-animation: animation-home-background 15000ms infinite;
    -moz-animation: animation-home-background 15000ms infinite;
    -o-animation: animation-home-background 15000ms infinite;
    animation: animation-home-background 15000ms infinite;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-delay: 1s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animation-home-background {
    25%    {background: red; }
    50%   {background: blue; }
    100%  {background: red; }
}
@keyframes animation-home-background {
    25%    {background: red; }
    50%   {background: blue; }
    100%  {background: red; }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xj9t62a2/

Use "!Important" is a bad practice and can bring you much more complicated problems to solve.